# How could this be shortened?

Tags: c#, delegates, action, binarywriter

I have this piece of code right here:

```
public void SendID(int id)
{
    try
    {
        binaryWriter.Write((int)Command.ID);

        // part differening each time
        binaryWriter.Write(id);
        // end of part differing each time
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Error != null)
            Error(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
    }
}
```

I want to generalize this function since the try/catch & Write(Command) thing is always equal on each of those methods. Now I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Basically I thought of a method saying something like this:

```
public void SendCommand(Command cmd, Action<BinaryWriter> action)
{
    try
    {
        binaryWriter.Write((int)Command.ID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Error != null)
            Error(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
    }
}
```

Then however I couldn't specify any other parameters which I might have (such as string message).

Another possibility would be changing the parameters to type object but then the `BinaryWriter` doesn't know what to access and I would have to do an explicit conversation each time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fine.  You can call your new method along the following lines:

`SendCommand(cmd, binaryWriter => binaryWriter.DoSomething(msg));`

Comment: oh yeah that's cool =) but sometimes I'd like to do more than that :S well I think LINQ makes this possible :) thanks!